# Apache ssl/https для виртуальных хостов

Tags: apache, ssl, https, virtual-hosts

Добрый день. 
Вопрос такой, есть сервер дебиан, апач, мускул, на нем хосты.

Решил на один из хостов поставить ssl для доступа по https.
Получилось:

1 - https ://site.com

n - http ://site2.com

Все хорошо, протокол поднялся и все работает.
Но недавно заметил что так же протокол срабатывает и на другие домены, у которых нет ни ssl ни включенного https.

На сколько я понимаю причина в том что на 443 -й откликается сайт с ssl  по https, но домен то не его, то есть https ://site.com должен отвечать, а https ://site2.com не должен так как у него нет сертификата.

То есть когда перехожу по https ://site2.com открывается контент первого сайта но домен в адресе https ://site2.com.

Собственно вопрос как правильно настроить, https так что бы другие сайты без ssl  не отвечали на https запросы?

Comment: Я дополнил ответ, посмотрите, теперь должно помочь.

Comment: Точно такая-же фигня, у меня все сайты на http, через такие виртуалхосты `<VirtualHost *:80>`. Добавил один virtualhost на ssl, 443-й порт `<VirtualHost *:443>`, теперь если на любой из http сайтов зайти через https, открывается этот единственный сайт на `<VirtualHost *:443>`.
Я так и не понял, автор нашел решение?

Answer (score 1):

Дело в том, что при подключении через SSL **сначала** устанавливается защищенное соединение по сертификату, и только **потом** происходит передача запроса, в том числе заголовка Host, указывающего, к какому сайту идет обращение. Поэтому если у вас на одном IP-адресе и порту висит несколько сайтов, все они будут открываться по сертификату, который настроен для этого IP/порта.

Вам необходимо явно указать, какой виртуальный хост отвечает на порту 443 (SSL), его имя должно быть таким же, как указано в сертификате. А для остальных виртуальных хостов явно прописать, что они должны слушать только порт 80.

Кроме того, важно учесть нюанс, что если в Apache пришел запрос на какой-то IP/порт с указанием заголовка `Host: XXX`, а он не смог найти для него виртуальный хост с `ServerName XXX` или `ServerAlias XXX`, то он передаст запрос на обработку в **первый виртуальный хост, подходящий по IP/порту**. Поэтому если вы хотите, чтобы при запросе несуществующего на данном IP/порту хоста отдавался не сайт, а какая-то заглушка, вам необходимо сконфигурировать `VirtualHost` с этой заглушкой и поставить ее раньше всех других `VirtualHost` на этом IP/порту.

Резюме:

### Не делайте так

Не указывайте виртуальные хосты без указания порта.

```
<VirtualHost *>
    #       ^^^ нет порта!
    # это приведет к ошибкам/неожиданному поведению
</VirtualHost>
```

### Указывайте порт для виртуальных хостов

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # сайт без SSL
    ...
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    # сайт с SSL
    ...
</VirtualHost>
```

Если используется несколько сертификатов SSL для разных сайтов, их нужно разнести на разные IP, например:

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:443>
    ServerName ssl-site1.com 
    ...
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 127.0.0.2:443>
    ServerName ssl-site2.com
    ...
</VirtualHost>
```

Ну или на разные порты (443, 1443, 2443 и т. д.), но это не очень удобно.

### Создайте заглушку для несуществующего сайта

Если вы не хотите, чтобы по запросу несуществующего сайта отдавался контент первого `VirtualHost`, подошедшего по IP/порту, сделайте на этом IP/порту заглушку и разместите ее **перед** остальными виртуальными хостами:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    # заглушка для SSL
    ServerName host-does-not-exist-stub.tech
    DocumentRoot /var/www/stub/public_html
    ...
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    # сайт с SSL
    ServerName real-ssl-site.ru
    DocumentRoot /var/www/real-ssl-site.ru/public_html
    ...
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Благодарен за внимание, но все же все хосты в формате 
<VirtualHost *:80>
Сайт с ssl в формате:
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
с 80 - го редирект на https... 
Ситуация уходшается, так как другие сайты начали индексироватся с https + REQUEST_URI с сайта с https 

Вопрос как отделить https от остальных хостов....?

Comment: Напишите три ссылки: 1) сайт на ssl 2) два сайта, которые тоже открываются по ssl, но не должны.

Comment: Пока временное решение выглядит так, но как по мне оно не грамотное... 
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=site.com
RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R,L]

Comment: Так а существуют ли три ссылки, о которых я спрашивал? Это важно. Если неправильно по ssl отдается один (и только один) сайт, то это может быть первый виртуальный хост в апаче, ну или то, что открывается при входе просто по ip.    Это один случай. Если сайтов несколько неправильно отдается, то это другой случай, надо внимательнее смотреть конфиг этих сайтов.

Comment: Мне кажется, я понял. Сейчас дополню ответ.

Comment: Самое интересное у меня есть прописаны все порты, все хосты отдельно друг от друга. Есть даже по умолчанию и хост http и https. В моем случае апач просто игнорируя домен ломится как слон, с открытым https, к хосту который слушает 443 порт. Завтра попробую добавить еще один сертификат и посмотрю че он будит чудить... А так вопрос открыт.

Comment: Так что, не помогло сделать заглушку на том же ip/порту?